# Cannot add/ subtract/ multiply/ divide two numbers from two textfields

Tags: java, string, integer, addition

When I run this it will display the two inputs together. For example 1 + 2 will come out to 12. I know that this string has to somehow be changed to an integer but I am lost on how to do so. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
private void     
jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                           
jLabel1.setText (String.valueOf(jTextField1.getText() +
jTextField2.getText()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values from JTextFields are Strings. If you want to do arithmetic on them you have to cast them to appropriate Numeric type like Integer or Double.

`jLabel1.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()) +
Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText())));`

Comment: `setText()` method expects a `String` argument, not an `int`. You need to convert `int` to `String` inside parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that this string has to somehow be changed to an integer but I
>   am lost on how to do so.

You are right. That's indeed the problem. Extracting a string number to int is very easy to achieve using `Integer.parseInt` method.

```
private void     
jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                           
jLabel1.setText (String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()) +
Initeger.parseInt(jTextField2.getText())));
```